# Convert Apple Emoji (String) to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I need all Apple Emojis.
 I can get all the emojis and put them into a *String* by copying them from the site [getemoji](http://getemoji.com) but in my app i need the emojis in the right order **as images**.
Is there a nice way to convert the emojis I copy into a String to a *UIImage*?
Or a better solution to get all the Apple emojis in the right order?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's an updated answer with the following changes:

- **Centered**: Used [`draw(at:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1533109-draw) instead of [`draw(in:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1529855-draw) for centering the text within the resulting UIImage
- **Correct Size**: Used [`size(withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-size) for having a resulting UIImage of size that correlates to the actual size of the font.
- **Comments**: Added comments for better understanding

**Swift** 5

```
import UIKit
extension String {
    func textToImage() -> UIImage? {
        let nsString = (self as NSString)
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1024) // you can change your font size here
        let stringAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let imageSize = nsString.size(withAttributes: stringAttributes)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0) //  begin image context
        UIColor.clear.set() // clear background
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: imageSize)) // set rect size
        nsString.draw(at: CGPoint.zero, withAttributes: stringAttributes) // draw text within rect
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() // create image from context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext() //  end image context

        return image ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

**Swift** 3.2

```
import UIKit
extension String {
    func textToImage() -> UIImage? {
        let nsString = (self as NSString)
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1024) // you can change your font size here
        let stringAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        let imageSize = nsString.size(attributes: stringAttributes)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0) //  begin image context
        UIColor.clear.set() // clear background
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: imageSize)) // set rect size
        nsString.draw(at: CGPoint.zero, withAttributes: stringAttributes) // draw text within rect
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() // create image from context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext() //  end image context

        return image ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning an optional
extension String {
    func textToImage() -> UIImage? {
if you have a default empty image
return image ?? UIImage()

Comment: Got an Objective-C version of this?

Answer (score 107):

### Updated for Swift 4.1

Add this extension to your project

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    func image() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        UIColor.white.set()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        (self as AnyObject).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)])
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

The code above draws the current `String` to an Image Context with a white background color and finally transform it into a `UIImage`.

Now you can write

[image]

### Example

Given a list of ranges indicating the unicode values of the emoji symbols

```
let ranges = [0x1F601...0x1F64F, 0x2702...0x27B0]
```

you can transform it into a list of images

```
let images = ranges
    .flatMap { $0 }
    .compactMap { Unicode.Scalar($0) }
    .map(Character.init)
    .compactMap { String($0).image() }
```

Result:

[image]

> I cannot guarantee the list of ranges is complete, you'll need to search for it by yourself

Comment: @Danny182: Please see my update. Next time please create a new question if you have more requests.

Comment: with the ranges won't work because they would be all mixed (the new ones have strange unicode). I have all the emojis in a array[String] @appzYourLife

Comment: But this is not vector based graphics anymore

Comment: Is it possible to make background transparent?

Comment: Set the drawing origin to `CGPoint(x: 2, y: -1)` and the font size to 34 and the emojis will also be centered and fit into the image

Comment: @Jonauz : Did you try `UIColor.clear.set()` instead of `UIColor.white.set()` ?

Comment: For a 128×128 image, I used 120pt font with the origin at `CGPoint(x: 0, y: -5)`.

Comment: @OleksiiNezhyborets emoji art is bitmap already, so nothing is actually lost (apart from resolution)

Answer (score 12):

Same thing for Swift 4:

```
extension String {
    func emojiToImage() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 35)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        UIColor.white.set()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size)
        UIRectFill(rect)
        (self as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)])
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Updated *@Luca Angeletti* answer for Swift 3.0.1

```
extension String {

    func image() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 35)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
        UIColor.white.set()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size)
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size))
        (self as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)])
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 4.2

I really liked @Luca Angeletti solution. I hade the same question as @jonauz about transparent background. So with this small modification you get the same thing but with clear background color.

I didn't have the rep to answer in a comment.

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    func emojiToImage() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 35)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        UIColor.clear.set()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size)
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size))
        (self as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)])
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5: ( with optional fontSize, imageSize and bgColor)

use it like this:

```
let image      = "".image()
let imageLarge = "".image(fontSize:100)
let imageBlack = "".image(fontSize:100, bgColor:.black)
let imageLong  = "".image(fontSize:100, imageSize:CGSize(width:500,height:100))
```

```
import UIKit

extension String
{
    func image(fontSize:CGFloat = 40, bgColor:UIColor = UIColor.clear, imageSize:CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage?
    {
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let imageSize = imageSize ?? self.size(withAttributes: attributes)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
        bgColor.set()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize)
        UIRectFill(rect)
        self.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [.font: font])
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: In your answer emoji is not centered

Comment: @VitalikKizlov Refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339365/10830091) for this and feel free (you or this answer's author Jolly Jinx) to edit this Swift5 answer based on mine. Use [`draw(at:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1533109-draw) instead of `draw(in:withAttributes:)`.

Answer (score 3):

Updated version of @Luca Angeletti's answer using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`:

```
extension String {
    func image() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { (context) in
            (self as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually much simpler than suggested answers.

```
extension String {
    func image(pointSize: CGFloat, backgroundColor: UIColor = .clear) -> UIImage {
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize)
        let emojiSize = self.size(withAttributes: [.font: font])

        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: emojiSize).image { context in
            backgroundColor.setFill()
            context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: emojiSize))
            self.draw(at: .zero, withAttributes: [.font: font])
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot from playground]

Answer (score 1):

This variation is based on [@Luca's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809531/2985369) accepted answer, but allows you to optionally customize the point size of the font, should result in a centered image, and doesn't make the background color white.

```swift
extension String {
    func image(pointSize: CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize) -> UIImage? {
        let nsString = self as NSString
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize)

        let size = nsString.size(withAttributes: [.font: font])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        nsString.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [.font: font])
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```