# Tint an emoji "image"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

This interface has two `UIButton`s and each one has an emoji. Because I can't afford graphics right now and that's what we're using.

[image]

For normal images, I am able to tint using this code, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979595/300224

```
let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

However that does not work (of course in this situation since there is no `UIImage`.

Is there any approach I can use in this situation to tint the button?

Comment: [Create an image from the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809425/convert-apple-emoji-string-to-uiimage) then tint the image as you know how.

Comment: There are plenty of open source assets available for you to use, especially for such common/generic items as microphones and speakers.

Comment: @Alexander I agree with you, I am not sure what the point is to try tint some simple basic icons when this apparantly isn't a graphic manipulation app that needs to.

Answer (score 2):

You can **not change the color** of the example images you provide in the way you think, as the `tintColor` method you are thinking of will "paint over" all your existing pixels, you will only have a flat shape with your color.

However, there are [custom manipulations](https://gist.github.com/lynfogeek/4b6ce0117fb0acdabe229f6d8759a139) that can be done, and you can play around with [Cor eImage Filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/) to achieve some form of effect that suits your needs if possible.

Related:

[To convert your Emoji to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809425/convert-apple-emoji-string-to-uiimage)

Above answers the question in the title provided. In your case:

> Because I can't **afford graphics** right now and that's what we're using.

There are no solutions.