# Can't take SCNNode from SceneView in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, scnnode

I'm trying to move `SCNNode` and I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403042/7157562).

But when I do:

```
let start = sceneView.node(for: first)
```

my application freezes and Xcode doesn't do anything.

**EDIT:**

```
func startBouncing(time: TimeInterval) {

    guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSCNView,
    let first = anchors.first, 
    let start = sceneView.node(for: first),
    let last = anchors.last, 
    let end = sceneView.node(for: last)
    else { return }

    if ballNode.parent == nil {
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
    }

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(SCNNode.transform))
    animation.fromValue = start.transform
    animation.toValue = end.transform
    animation.duration = time
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    ballNode.removeAllAnimations()
    ballNode.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Comment: If it crashes, please show the crash log :) Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister No, It doesn't crash. It's doing… nothing. I've made two breakpoints: one oin line with code  'let start = sceneView.node(for: first' and other in the next line. And second breakpoint wasn’t called.

Comment: Can you show more code. What is `sceneView`? What is `first`? etc...

Comment: sceneView is ARSCNView, and first is ARAnchor. All code can be found by clicking on the link. It isn't mine. I've just trying to use it

Comment: You should add that info in your question.

Comment: Try `Debug` - > `Deactivate Breakpoints`. And what does mean `freezes`? Camera freezes or what? Explain yourself, please.

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev `Try Debug - > Deactivate Breakpoints` for what? 
And yes, camera freezes and xcode do nothing