# Swift 3: How to access the value of matrix_float3x3 in a 48-byte CFData?

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, ios11, cfdata

I'm trying to access intrinsic matrix following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159895/9296667).

By running the commend below, I was able to get a 48-byte [AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyobject), and I further convert it into a [CFData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfdata-rv9).

```
let camData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil)
```

However, I checked the output of sampleBuffer in `CMSampleBuffer.h`:

```
/*! @constant   kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix
     @abstract  Indicates the 3x3 camera intrinsic matrix applied to the current sample buffer.
     @discussion Camera intrinsic matrix is a CFData containing a matrix_float3x3, which is column-major.
        ....
 */
CM_EXPORT const CFStringRef kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix  // CFData (matrix_float3x3) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_11_0);
```

How should I access the value in the `matrix_float3x3` from the `CFData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

- Use the bridging from `CFData` to `NSData` to `Data`, and
- the `withUnsafeBytes` method to get a pointer of the desired
  type to the data bytes,
- `.pointee` to dereference the pointer.

Example:

```
if let camData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil) as? Data {
    let matrix: matrix_float3x3 = camData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }

    // ...

}
```

The pointer type (`$0` inside the closure) is inferred from the context
as `UnsafePointer<matrix_float3x3>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update of Martin R's answer since the `withUnsafeBytes` had been deprecated:

```swift
if let camData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, 
                                 key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, 
                                 attachmentModeOut: nil) as? Data {
    let matrix = camData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: matrix_float3x3.self) }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's version of Martin R's answer for objective-c:

```
CFTypeRef cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil);
if(cameraIntrinsicData != nil){
    CFDataRef cfdr = (CFDataRef)(cameraIntrinsicData);
    matrix_float3x3 *camMatrix = (matrix_float3x3 *)(CFDataGetBytePtr(cfdr));
}
```